# How to generate a random date in Julia?

Tags: julia

I would like to generate a random date in an interval, say a random date in 2000-2010. Naturally it would need to take care of leap years.

How would I do this in Julia?

Comment: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/dates-randomly-generating-datetime-values/15156/2 and truncate to a date?

Comment: Indeed, I saw that example before asking about this, but it was written in 2018, and somehow that solution doesn't feel quite clean enough. Maybe a better solution is possible now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that by date you mean a day you can do:

```
julia> using Dates

julia> rand(Date(2000, 1, 1):Day(1):Date(2010, 12, 31))
2004-03-13
```

This constructs a range of `Date`s which is efficient as it doesn't have to allocate an array with all `Date`s, and then picks a random one in that range.

Comment: This answer demonstrates what is nice about Julia in so many ways :)